# c# Change Background Of SelectNode In TreeView

Tags: c#, colors, treeview, nodes

I want change the background color of the Nodes in a TreeView control, so that when a user selects a node, the background colors change from the selected selected node to the top most parent within the TreeView.

Here's a visual example of what I am after:

[image: TreeView node background example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your image I'll assume you're using Windows Forms. So, this is the code you need to achieve the desired functionality having a form with a Treeview called treeview1 in this sample:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private readonly Color selectedColor = Color.Red;
    private readonly Color normalColor = Color.Transparent;

    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.ByKeyboard &&
            e.Action != TreeViewAction.ByMouse)
            return;

        ResetAllNodes(treeView1.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>());
        ChangeBackground(e.Node);
    }

    private void ResetAllNodes(IEnumerable<TreeNode> nodes)
    {
        var treeNodes = nodes as TreeNode[] ?? nodes.ToArray();
        if (!treeNodes.Any())
            return;

        foreach (var node in treeNodes)
        {
            node.BackColor = normalColor;
            ResetAllNodes(node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>());
        }
    }

    private void ChangeBackground(TreeNode node)
    {
        node.BackColor = selectedColor;
        if (node.Parent == null)
            return;

        ChangeBackground(node.Parent);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!